# How to display formatted output in different colors using console.writeline

Tags: c#

Is it possible to display formatted output in different colors:

```
console.WriteLine(“First {0} second{1} ”,  firstString, secondString)
```

I would like to display a variation while showing the output, like **firstString** in one color and **secondString** in another color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `Console.Write()` if you want to use different colors in one line write like this:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.Write("First  ");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.Write("{0} ", firstString);
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.Write("second ");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.Write("{0} ", secondString);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do multiple `Console.Write()` calls and set colors for the console like so:

```
class Program {
    static void Main( string[] args ) {
      PrintColoredString( "First", "firstString", ConsoleColor.Green );
      PrintColoredString( "second", "secondString", ConsoleColor.Cyan );
      Console.ResetColor();
      Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void PrintColoredString(string key, string value, ConsoleColor color) {
      Console.ForegroundColor = color;
      Console.Write( "{0} {1} ", key, value );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a [small plugin](https://github.com/silkfire/Pastel)<sup>†</sup> (available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pastel)) that allows you to easily wrap your strings in **[ANSI color codes](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-ansi-color-codes-in-net-console-apps/)**.

[image]

It works by extending the `String` object, and the syntax is as follows:

```
"color me".Pastel("#1E90FF");
```

After that it's ready to be used by any of the  `Console.Write*` methods.

<sup>†</sup> I'm the creator of this library

Comment: I found this super interesting, but there is a drawback... the terminal environment must support processing of ANSI sequences; if I cannot assure that, I should probably stick with changing the Console´s back- and fore-color properties. At least, I learned something...

Comment: @Matze Thank you for your reply. Which consoles have you tried with so far? I've tested it on some older Windows consoles and if it can't produce the exact color, it approximates instead, which I think is a fair fallback solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
```

See [C# Console Color](http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-color).

As far as I know, it is not possbile to use multiple colors in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible by using `Console.ForegroundColor` and `Console.BackgroundColor`, but you need to split your `Console.WriteLine` call out to Console.Write calls, so that you don't get a newline between components.

Be careful for thread-safety here, as you don't want lines on top of each other, with different colour outputs - it could make you very ill.